# Word usage, making something "compatible"

Tags: vocabulary

I was lost doing this. This is the sense I want to convey:

> Studying and working at the same time can be difficult because you need to accomodate both those activities into your daily life, take some time of study to your work, and viceversa.

My idea was to write:

> "When you study and work you need to compatibilize both these activities" (meaning to fit these activities in your schedule, etc etc)

Then someone pointed to me that the word "compatibilize" does not exist. How do I convey the same meaning? .

I did a translation from my language and the result was *reconcile*, but when I look it up on a dictionary reconcile gives me the idea of a couple fighting about something for example and then setting aside their differences.

Answer (score 2):

"Reconcile" is indeed a good word here.

Yes, "reconcile" is used when two or more people or groups have a conflict, and then find a way to become friends again. Like, "Bob and I had a big fight, but then I apologized and we RECONCILED."

But "reconcile" can also mean to bring two ideas into agreement. Like, "Dr Jones re-evaluated the data and was able to RECONCILE his experimental results with what was predicted by the theory." It is common for accountants to talk about "reconciling the books", meaning, fixing any disagreements between numbers from different sources.

Another option is to simply replace the non-word "compatibilize" with "make compatible". Like, "When you both study and work, you need to make these activities compatible."

Side note: I'd say "both study and work" to make clear that you are talking about two different things. Otherwise the reader might think that you mean work at studying. It's common -- and maybe this is American English -- to talk about "working hard in school". Or you could stay "go to school and have a job".

Comment: Footnote: A synonym for _reconcile_ in the sense of scheduling is _deconflict_.